# Single case union type inside a union type

Tags: f#

I have the following union types:

```
type UserName = UserName of string

type LogLineType =
| UserName of UserName
| EmptyLine
```

and a function that returns the `LogLineType`:

```
let getLogLineType line =
    let userName = UserName "foo"
    userName
```

However, I keep getting a compile error saying

> The expression was expected to have type UserName but has type string

I understand it's trying to construct a `LogLineType` from a `UserName` type but how can I tell the compiler I am trying to construct a `UserName` from a `string` (the single case union)?

Comment: Two union cases with the same name is asking for difficulty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix that by using `UserName.UserName "foo"`:

```
let getLogLineType line =
    let userName = UserName.UserName "foo"
    userName;;
```

But as already said by @ildjarn in his comment, it's probably not wise to have to union cases with the same name.

Comment: It was probably expected that the compiler would still infer the correct type from the usage, but that is not the case. If there are ambiguities like this (or things like record types with fields of the same name), the compiler will instead use the type defined last if it is not qualified further.

Comment: That function has the type `'a -> UserName`. It's not clear from the OP whether that's the desired type, but from the name and presence of the `LogLineType` DU, I guess not. See my answer for an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear exactly which `UserName` you want the `getLogLineType` function to return, but the name of the function suggests the latter (the one which is a case of `LogLineType`).

In that case, you first need to turn the string into the first `UserName` case, and then turn *that* value into the second `UserName` case. In order to do that, you'll need to disambiguate a bit:

```
let getLogLineType line =
    let userName = UserName (UserName.UserName "foo")
    userName
```

This function has the type `'a -> LogLineType`.

As @ildjarn said in the comments, however, having two union cases with the same name is asking for trouble.

Comment: Thanks Mark, love your PluralSight course by the way!